# hibernate Dao references to external DB?

Tags: hibernate

originally all my entities are in one DB. for example I have 2 tables/classes: A and B,

A has a one-to-one mapping to B, so we can do A.getB(). and this generates a query on B table.

now let's say our DB becomes too crowded/busy, and we found that B table is very big, but accessed rarely, so we move B to another table (or even another datastore, for that matter, for example noSQL ).  now my question is, how is it possible to maintain the easy object graph traversal provided by hibernate?

originally, I could pull an A object:  A a = DaoForA.get(id_for_a); then I can do a.getB() without thinking about the underlying DB operation, as if everything is already in memory. now with the B table moved to another DB, is it still possible to achieve this transparent traversal? I assume that the A.hbm.xml should be changed in the  mapping  tags, since the B table no longer exists, so A.hbm.xml does not know the existence B, so this auto-retrieval can't be done?

Thanks a lot
Yang

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate entities can't have associations to entities from another database. Instead of using separate databases, see

1. if you really need to do this. If B is rarely used, letting it in the same DB won't do any harm. And if the database is too large, then buy a new hard disk: hardware is cheap.
2. if the database can be clustered.

Programming with Hibernate "as if everything is already in memory" is a recipe for disaster. You need to understand what Hibernate does behind the scene.